# Construct scala/akka Future from callback

Tags: scala, akka

I have such code example

```
val request: Defered[Int] = client.getSomeIntAsynFromSocket();

request.addCallBack(result => result.success[String])
request.addErrback(error => error.fail[Integer])
```

How is it possible to construct Future[Validation[String, Int]] from defered 'request' and available callbacks

==============================================

Solution from my own:

```
val f = Future {
    val queue = java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue[Validation[String, Int]](1)

    val request: Defered[Int] = client.getSomeIntAsynFromSocket();
    request.addCallBack(result => queue.add(result.success[String]))
    request.addErrback(error => queue(error.fail[Integer]))

    f.take
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Akka 2.x, put the method below somewhere you can reuse it by import.

```
def asFuture[T](d: Defered[T])(implicit e: ExecutionContext): Future[T] = {
  val p = Promise[T]()
  d.addCallback(r => p tryComplete Right(r))
  d.addErrback(e => p tryComplete Left(e))
  p.future
}

val f = asFuture(client.getIntAsynFromSocket())
```